# IntelliJ IDEA: how to enable imports for inner classes

Tags: intellij-idea

When I paste a code snippet with inner entity's(class or enum) name in it in IDEA 12 I get a dialog offering to import that entity's package. If class I'm working on and entity are in same package, IDEA just writes outer class name and a dot before entity's name. That bloats source much worse than if entity was imported in the import section at the file start. How to disable this kind of behaviour and force IDEA to import everything exclusively in import section?

Comment: IntelliJ knows Java better than you do.  I'm not exactly sure what you want to do, but I'd believe IntelliJ.  It only puts imports at the top when I use it.

Comment: @duffymo I've corrected question. Maybe now it will be clearer. Pasting code into other file having no entity imported leads to inline import. That means if there are 100 instances of entity in snippet each will be preceeded by entity's outer class name with a dot.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Honestly, when using inner classes outside its parent it JUST makes sense to reference the outer class instead of importing the inner class at the top level, otherwise, why is that class an inner class instead of a top level one? From my point of view, if you are consuming a inner class outside its parent at lot (you say 100 times) then, don't you think you should review your design?

Anyway, you can control the **Auto-Import** feature in IntelliJ at `Settings > Editor > General > Auto Import`.

In the other hand, if you want to **have imports for your inner classes** then go to `Settings > Editor > Code Style > Java > Imports` and mark the `Insert imports for inner classes` checkbox.

Comment: Thank you! Of course I'll refactor my code design after feature will be implemented. And I'll move my enum outside the class. Still importing in import section only is behavior I prefer.

Comment: I appreciate the answer though I am not sure I agree with the first statement. What about the use of the Entry inner class for the java Map collections class as an example of a class you use the inner one quite a bit?

Comment: Probably saying _review your design_ is a bit blunt. I do see the point of doing such imports in some localised places but since in Java all your imports are global to the file, you end up losing the benefit of the namespacing you receive by declaring the inner class. In other words, importing `Map.Entry` in a small, purpose-focused file is not a big deal. Don't think the same for doing such in a class that handles business logic and has many other imports alongside it, the `Map.` gives context to the reader to what that type relates to.